# getting bad request nextjs runtime error despite http 200 from graphql

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, next.js, graphql, apollo

using graphql to update a user's name in the database (in a nextjs/react app) but not sure how to handle runtime errors (e.g. name already exists). Throwing the error leads to a gets bad request runtime error, and if we `return` the error inside the resolver it leads to a unique constraint fail runtime error. Does anyone have any insight as to why the application is showing the bad request runtime error when there's already a try and catch and how to properly handle it?

nextjs/react code

```
const UPDATE_NAME = gql`
  mutation Mutation(
    $id: ID!
    $newName: String
  ) {
    updateName(
      id: $id
      name: $newName
    )
  }
`

  // useMutation from apollo client
  const [updateName, { data, loading, error }] =
    useMutation(UPDATE_NAME);

  return (
  <>
    {error && <span>Fail</span>}
    {data && <span>Success</span>}
  </>
);
```

typeDef

```
updateName(
      id: ID
      newName: String
): String
```

resolver

```
 try {
    user = await prisma.user.update({
      where: {
        id: id,
      },
      data: {
        name: newName,
      },
    });
  } catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof Prisma.PrismaClientKnownRequestError) {
      if (e.code === "P2002") {
        throw new UserInputError("Bad Request", { errors: e }); // leads to runtime error
        // return e // will lead to Invalid `prisma.user.update()` invocation error
      }
    }
  }

return user.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have any insight as to why the application is showing the bad request runtime error when there's already a try and catch and how to properly handle it?

In this part you catch the error but then you throw a new error. The new error you throw is not caught by anything.

```
  } catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof Prisma.PrismaClientKnownRequestError) {
      if (e.code === "P2002") {
        throw new UserInputError("Bad Request", { errors: e }); // leads to runtime error
        // return e // will lead to Invalid `prisma.user.update()` invocation error
      }
    }
  }
```

If this error is expected, you can return a non-error value and let the user know accordingly.

```
resolver:

} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof Prisma.PrismaClientKnownRequestError) {
    if (e.code === "P2002") {
      return {
        'id': 'duplicate'
      }
    }
  }
}


----

nextjs/react code:

return (
  <>
    {updateName.id === 'duplicate' && <span>Name already exists</span>}
    {error && <span>Fail</span>}
    {data && <span>Success</span>}
  </>
```

Another approach is to have `componentDidCatch` and handle the error that way.

Comment: is there a way to go about using the `error` in the `useMutation`?

Comment: returning the error inside the try catch also caused a runtime error for some reason